# ImportError: cannot import name 'google'

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to import this line below but I am getting this error.

```
from google import google
.
.
.
ImportError: cannot import name 'google'
```

These are the files I have installed. What am I missing?

```
$ pip list | grep google
google                             2.0.1    
google-api-core                    1.4.0    
google-api-python-client           1.7.4    
google-auth                        1.5.1    
google-auth-httplib2               0.0.3    
google-cloud-core                  0.28.1   
google-cloud-storage               1.12.0   
google-resumable-media             0.3.1    
googleapis-common-protos           1.5.3
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have another file named `google.py` somewhere in your path?

Comment: @wpercy Yes, it is within the same folder. Is that not the correct place?

Comment: it'll overwrite the name `google`, try renaming your file something like `my_google.py` and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is an official python package to use google's discovery services, you can't override the package name here, just rename your file with something else like `my_google_thing.py`, it will solve the import issue for you.